# Find the minimum number of zeros of $g(x)=(f'(x))^2+f(x)f''(x)$in the interval $[a, e]$ for the following given information.

Tags: calculus, solution-verification, maxima-minima, rolles-theorem

If $f(x)$ is twice differentiable function such that  $f(a)=0, f(b)=2,f(c)=–1, f(d) =2,f(e)=0$, where $a<b<c<d<e$, then find the minimum number of zeros of $g(x)=(f'(x))^2+f(x)f''(x)$in the interval $[a, e]$.

My attempt is as follows:-

By Intermediate value theorem, we can say following:

$1)$ There lies atleast one $c_1\in(b,c)$ such $f(c_1)=0$

$2)$ There lies atleast one $c_2\in(c,d)$ such that $f(c_2)=0$

$$g(x)=(f'(x))^2+f(x)f''(x)$$
$$g(x)=\dfrac{d(f(x)f'(x))}{dx}$$

Let, $h(x)=f(x)f'(x)$

$$h(a)=h(c_1)=h(c_2)=h(e)=0$$

There will be atleast three roots of $h'(x)$ by Rolle's theorem

By Rolle's theorem, we can also say following:-

$1)$ There lies atleast one $c_3\in(a,e)$ such that $f'(c_3)=0$

$2)$ There lies atleast one $c_4\in(b,d)$ such that $f'(c_4)=0$

As we have to find minimum no of roots, so it can be $c_1=c_3=c_4$

So $g(c_1)=f'(c_1)^2+f(c_1)f''(c_1)=0$, hence $c_1$ can be the root. We could have taken $c_2$ in place of $c_1$ but things would remain same.

So there should be minimum $4$ roots of $g(x)$. But actual answer is $6$. What am I missing here.

Answer (score 2):

Rolle on $(a,c_1)$ gives $c_3$ such that $f'(c_3)=0$

Rolle on $(c_1,c_2)$ gives $c_4$ such that $f'(c_4)=0$

Rolle on $(c_2,e)$ gives $c_5$ such that $f'(c_5)=0$

We have $a<c_3<c_1<c_4<c_2<c_5<e$ and f or f' vanish at these points and also $h=ff'$

Rolle applied to $h$ on each interval gives 6 zéros of $g$.